# en.json 'Not Found' when serving SB Admin Bootstrap 4 template

Tags: angular, angular-cli, zone.js

I am using this template:

https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4

On `ng serve` it is always throwing an error in console:

> GET
>   http://localhost:4200/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/master/dist/assets/i18n/en.json
>   404 (Not Found) - zone.js:2263
>
> ERROR Response {_body: "↵↵↵↵↵↵", status: 404,
>   ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}
>   core.es5.js:1020

How would you fix that error?

Comment: can you type http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/en.json in your browser if it is `404` or OK?

Comment: show this :

{
    "dashboard": "Dashboard",
    "charts": "Charts",
    "tables": "Tables",
    "forms": "Forms",
    "boostrapElement": "Boostrap Element",
    "boostrapGrid": "Boostrap Grid",
    "component": "Component",
    "menu": "Menu",
    "submenu": "Submenu",
    "blankpage": "Blank Page",
    "moretheme": "More Themes",
    "downloadNow": "Download Now",
    "language": "Language"
}

Comment: Show me how you reference that file in your code.

Comment: i dont know where is the reference from... beacuse is a tamplate. the first time i opened it , the error appeard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong path to `en.json`
It should be something like `http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/en.json`

**UPDATE:**
I just looked in to source. You need play with `app.module.ts` file lines 14 and 13 https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts#L14

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
    // for development
    // return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/master/dist/assets/i18n/', '.json');
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```